# How can I send push notifications to iOS without writing my own application?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I would like to send push notifications to iOS-based devices, but I don't want to write my own app.  From what I've gathered so far, to send a push notification using the Apple Push Notification Service I need to use the SSL certificates that were used to sign an application.

Basically, what I'm looking for is the iOS equivalent of [Notify My Android](https://www.notifymyandroid.com/), an app that you install on your Android device that has a web service with a simple [HTTP API](https://www.notifymyandroid.com/api.jsp) for sending notifications.

Comment: Hi J Collie. Thanks for the question. You can accomplish this using the Spontit API here: api.spontit.com

Comment: I had the exact same question.

Answer (score 16):

You can try :

- Boxcar : http://boxcar.io/
- Pushover : https://pushover.net/

Comment: @vokilam you need an app in order to use Parse

Comment: "Parse's hosted services will be fully retired on January 28, 2017. "

Comment: Boxcar is no long available on the US App Store, and Pushover costs $5 after the first week.

Answer (score 5):

Use https://pushed.co/

SEND PUSH NOTIFICATIONS WITHOUT DEVELOPING YOUR OWN APP
Pushed allows you to send real-time push notifications to
iOs, Android and Desktop (Chrome, Firefox & Safari) devices.

(Just found it and also found your question.)

Comment: It's a really nice app. But if you're looking for something free it's not suitable if you want to be able to push notifications to individual users. While basic features are free, this ability requires Pro version (49 €/month).

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible under iOS. You only can send push notifications to a specific (your own)  app.

Comment: Yes, what I was hoping that someone else had written an app and set up a 3rd party web service with a simple HTTP API

Comment: This won't work either, because he would need to share his provisioning profile and his developer account with the public which is strictly forbidden.

Comment: @yinkou Have you seen https://pushed.co/ ? SEND PUSH NOTIFICATIONS 
WITHOUT DEVELOPING YOUR OWN APP
Pushed allows you to send real-time push notifications to
iOs, Android and Desktop (Chrome, Firefox & Safari) devices.

Comment: Dude, this was 5 years ago.

Comment: @jcollie Yeah this is doable with the Spontit API. https://api.spontit.com/

Answer (score 3):

An option can be to have your users install telegram app and have them talk to your bot. The bot can push notifications to individual users and can even listen for commands.

Comment: You can't push to individual users with Telegram. Only channels. See the sendMessage description here: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api   

Note it says "chat_id" and the description is "Unique identifier for the target chat or username of the target channel (in the format @channelusername)"

With Spontit, you can push to individual users: api.spontit.com

Answer (score 2):

When you set up your push notifications for the app, Apple is very strict about the usage.  You can only send push notifications to that specific app, and only from your developer account and profile.

There is no way to have a third party program for this because of these restrictions, so no, **this is not possible**.

For more information check out the [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html) on Push Notifications.

Comment: A little bit more Google surfing turned up Prowl: http://www.prowlapp.com/api.php Is this not doing exactly what I had hoped? Or are they not using APNS in the background?

Comment: This seems to be good. However, you will need to input your own apn key for your own apps.  There are plenty of APIs that do that.  Also, all devices will need to have prowl installed according to the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

did you find any app's that could do what your after? If not, check out EasyAPN on the Mac App Store or website http://www.abdullahselek.com/2013/08/08/easyapn/.

Its an app where you put in the token and payload and press sent (it will detect your certificates stored in your key chain which you can select from).

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with [PushBullet](https://www.pushbullet.com/) (which has a web API) or [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com) (which does not seem to have a public API, but has a bunch of other triggers).

Answer (score 0):

As @yinkou and @DGund pointed out, none of these push notification platforms (Pusher, Boxcar.io, pushover.net) can work around the Apple Push Notification rule of having a registered app.

So the answer is a DEFINITIVELY NO. YOU CANNOT send iOS push notifications without your own app.

Comment: Hi Devy, You can send notifications if you do it through another app that provides their own API for doing so. For example, see the Spontit API: https://pypi.org/project/spontit/

Comment: Updated Spontit API docs: https://api.spontit.com/